# How do I stack these pictures vertically on a small screen?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to stack these picture vertically on a small screen. So one
column instead of two
I'm trying to stack these picture vertically on a small screen. So one
column instead of two:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-6 col-ms-12">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img
              class="img-responsive img-fluid"
              src="project-images/skylit.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 sm-col-12">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img
              class="img-responsive img-fluid"
              src="project-images/skit4.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-6 xl-col">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img
              class="img-responsive img-fluid"
              src="project-images/skit6.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 sm-col-12">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img
              class="img-responsive img-fluid"
              src="project-images/skylit2.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 sm-col-12">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img
              class="img-responsive img-fluid"
              src="project-images/lvr.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 sm-col">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img
              class="img-responsive img-fluid"
              src="project-images/gym.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
/* Please improve your content by showing what you tried so far */
```

e. G. Added "some" to "thing", Edited column count, I'm not that into HTML but you get what you could write here

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using bootstrap  the classes should be col-sm-12, I see you are using sm-col-12 and col-ms-12. That should make the element take all space in grid.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Start from smallest class too: class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"